# How can I find this position to fix the truncated escape

Tags: python, syntax-error, unicode-escapes, truncated

I have a really really long multiline string like 500 plus lines. It is a bunch of payloads used for testing and has quite a lot of special characters in it. So of course one of these special characters cause a problem and I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16321-16322: truncated \xXX escape
```

But the main problem is I can't find where the issue is cuz the error highlighting only highlights the beginning of the string and the error is at position 16321-16322, is there a way to find the error without counting my way there...

Comment: Could you just use Python for this? `print(test_string[16310:16330])`

Comment: You can use the method @kemp suggested to locate the special character.
Then you can use the filter() to filter the content of the string.
Check details in the following blog link

https://www.tutsmake.com/python-remove-special-characters-from-string/

You can also prefilter special characters you dont need even without locating them for example ',;&* etc

Comment: @AModgil and thank you this made it easier